# Combine publishers from a dynamic list not updating

Tags: swift, combine

### Background

I have several publishers which need to be grouped together, in this example there is `varA` (Publisher A1), `varB` (Publisher B1) and `varC` (An array of Publishers C1..n). The array of publishers in C is dynamic, as in they are constantly changing. However, the list of `varC`'s publishers is only ever evaluated once at startup and the CombineLatest never truly subscribes to the list of publishers. When I add to the list or take away the `combiner` publisher doesn't pay attention to it.

Below is a very simplified version of the problem

```swift
class GenericModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dynamicList: [Publishable] = []

    lazy let varA = Just(1)
    lazy let varB = Just(2)
    var varC: AnyPublisher<[Int], Never> {
        return Publishers.MergeMany(self.dynamicList.map{ $0.getPublisher })
            .collect()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    lazy var combiner: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> = {
        Publishers.CombineLatest3(
            varA,
            varB,
            varC
        ).map { v1, v2, v3 in
            return v1 == 0 && v2 == 0 && v3.allSatisfy({ $0 == 0 })
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }()
}
```

In this case, I have a subscription to `combiner`. However whenever it is run, the total number of values in varC is 0. This is also confirmed by breaking on `varC`s closure, which only gets instantiated once.

I've tried a couple of things to make the subscription to `dynamicList` dynamic but it never seems to update.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are all the dynamic publishers complete? Otherwise, `.collect` of `varC` would wait for completion from the upstream `MergeMany`, which in turn waits for a completion from all the publishers it got from a dynamic list

Comment: @NewDev ah that makes sense, none of them are complete. I totally misread `collect`'s use case. Do you know what I can use in collect's place to essentially combinelatest on all of the dynamic list of publishers?

Comment: I don't know if there's a trivial way to implement a combineLatest-like functionality for an array of publishers.